# What are the immigration officers going to ask or require once I land in Hamburg?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, germany, hamburg

This is my first time travelling as an adult and alone. I am travelling from Panama. I already checked and I don't need a visa. What are the things that I will need? I will be visiting someone I met online, that's why I will be staying in a hotel for the first 4 days, and then depending on how things works, I will be staying with the person, or I will make another reservation for the time left. He already gave me his address, but I'm not sure if they will ask for something else.

Comment: first of all, do you know and trust this person? 
they'll probably ask when will you leave, and saying that it depends on how it goes with this person is not a great answer.

Comment: Yes I have my return ticket. We've been talking for a time now, on video, calls, etc The point is that my reservation is not made for all of the days because I still don't know how things will work.

Comment: @Kristell Thompson I’ve travelled extensively as a lone female and I’d be very wary of being in a foreign country (do you speak the language?) without knowing for sure where I’d be staying. Can you make a refundable reservation just in case? And I’d be making sure I had a daily ‘check in back home’ arrangement, and that I knew where the safe areas are in Hamburg.

Comment: @Traveller Yes, I mean I I've been trying to find refundable reservations but haven't found any. I am doing this because I found the ticket really cheap and I bought it, but not because he forced me in any way as his plans to come here were in October and then I bought the ticket. He gave me his adress and I looked for the area and it's a normal area, also, my parents know all of the information, adresses and I will buy a SIM card to stay communicated. I know this may seem a bit complicated to understand for a lot of people but he has even talk to my parents via skype, & he is willing to help

Comment: @KristellThompson, go to a website where you can book hotels or hostels, (like booking.com or hostelworld,) and book one of their rooms or bed where they say you can cancel for free till the day you are expected to arrive. Just make sure you do cancel before you are expected, otherwise you will have to pay. Mostly you need a credit card for this but there are a few which do not ask for a card.

Comment: I think it's likely that the border police will ask nothing more than how long you are staying, which you can calculate from your return flight, but I would also have some proof of funds.

Comment: I also have reservations for different tours, I think the best option is to get a refundable accomodation and to cancel if I need to. Thanks @Willeke

Comment: Thanks! I think if I have a refundable reservation for all of the days they won't have any problems, is that right? @AndrewLazarus

Comment: You should have reasonable pocket money available. You don't need cash, but if not, you should show you have a credit/debit card with enough to get food.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Totally, I have a credit card plus cash, also my return ticket! I don't plan on staying, have my whole life in Panama :) Just trying to do things right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several points of advice.

- While online dating is becoming much more common these days, you should realize that your situation has the **potential** of becoming a problem for you and an even greater likelihood of being **seen** as a problem by people like the immigration officials. (Notice how you wrote the neutral "person" and I immediately leapt to assumptions.)
- Even if you are madly in love (*especially* if you are madly in love ...), do nothing to hurt your *long-term* chances of living together with your friend. Part of that means making credible plans to leave Germany after the planned end of your visit, and to come back *later*. Possibly for another brief visit, possibly after application for a residence permit.
- You should have a **clear idea** where you can stay if things don't work out. That doesn't have to be a firm reservation in a hotel, you could also have the contact details (and price ranges) of several hostels for young tourists with you. They offer anything from single bedrooms to 12-bed dormitories at different prices. You should also know how to contact a battered women's shelter, they would be more competent to help you if there are problems in that regard.

So, with these things said:

- You need a passport which is valid for more than 3 months, no older than 10 years, and contains biometric data.
- As a visa-free national, you can arrive for *tourism* or business trips. Do not ever suggest that you might like to stay, or that you are not sure if you will actually take your planned return trip. (And that should be the truth and not just a lie. Leave again, let your friend visit you, see where it leads. See below.)
- You have to have money or tickets for your return flight and money to cover your stay. There is no fixed rate for that, but something like like €50/day should be the absolute minimum. Also health insurance.
- You can show your initial hotel reservation, and (honestly) say that you don't know where you'll go from there, that you have the contact details from several affordable hostels (see above).

I think the answer by Michael is *wrong*, and note how it was downvoted. You can get away with not volunteering information, but **do not lie.** One lie leads to the next, sooner or later one lie will be exposed, and then you will have a file that says you lied to an EU official.

I know several couples where a German partner married a partner from outside the EU. In each case it was a process that started with visits before it came to a residency permit and then to the marriage. That's the *latest* point where the authorities will ask if it is a [sham marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_of_convenience) or a true one, and little lies at an earlier stage will come to hurt you.

Comment: totally loved your answer! it's the most complete! btw, I said "person" as I wasn't sure of telling people my personal life, but as I said before I've been talking to him quite a time now, and he has been trying to make things easier for me. In fact he told me the same about looking for refundable reservations, as we're both hoping this works out but at the same time we're both scared it doesn't. I don't plan on staying, have a credit card, cash and my return ticket, he also gave me his adress but I'll follow your advise about having a list of other places with the prices Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -6):

immigration in Germany don't ask as many questions as the US, but they will certainly ask you why you are travelling to Germany and what you are intending to do. The simplest answer is: "I'm visiting friends in Hamburg." If they ask where you know the people from (unlikely to be asked this), you are free to make a white lie and say: "German friends I met in Panama."
As for the private story, ignore the strange questions from other posters. In the days of the Internet there are much weirder ways to meet people.

Comment: Advocating deceit when entering a country is ill advised, and may backfire, resulting in an entry refusal. It also contravenes TSE policy, as does your disparagement of other users.

Comment: @Giorgio The best option is to look for an refundable accomodation so I can cancel in case I won't use it

Comment: Do not lie.  That's far worse than feeling silly.  The Officers have heard much weirder, but still legal, things than visiting online friends.

Comment: Repeat it: Do not lie. Especially pointless lies. Doesn't matter if you met someone in Panama or online, and is probably harder to believe.